# Deploying an existing .NET application to IBM App Connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, ibm-app-connect

I have an existing .NET MVC application and its a feedback giving application. I need to deploy and integrate this application to App Connect. As I am new to IBM domain, I am completely stuck at where to start the process. Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? you'll need to post some code and more information on what you're attempting to get more help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not about coding but about procedural steps for deploying an application to IBM AppConnect. Things are unclear with IBM documentation, like the tools or methods or servers to do this. I believe somebody already tried this  can light me up.